Написать программу по работе в go с .bat файлами
Написать программу, которая вычисляет квадрат числа и выводит результат на экран. Входные данные должны сообщаться как параметр командной строки.
Инициатор вычислений: [*.bat]–файл со следующим содержимым:
@SET /A A = 3
prog %A%
pause

где prog – имя исполняемого [*.exe]-файла разработанной программы, а 3-число, для которого проводятся вычисления.
Использовать язык Golang.

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что наше сообщество это не фриланс биржа

К сожалению, вы единственный, кто участвовал в этом "голосовании". Приходите со своим мнением на другие платформы
